# Como visualizar recaptcha v3 en contact form 7

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-plugin

Hola active el plugin contact form 7 y le puse las llaves en el boton integracion

y no me muestra el recaptcha.

```
<label> Your Name (required)
[text* your-name] </label>
```

Your Email (required)
    [email* your-email]

Your Phone(required)
[tel* your-phone]

Subject
    [text your-subject]

Your Message
    [textarea your-message minlength:20 maxlength:500]

Please copy below the code : [captchac captcha-1 captcha-778 size:l fg:#ffffff bg:#000000]
[captchar captcha-1] 
[honeypot honeypot-748 id:MedEZCF7HS move-inline-css:true]
[submit "Send"]

Comment: Para la versiòn 3, ya no es necesario la casilla de verificaciòn, por lo que no se muestra el widget. Puedes encontrar màs informaciòn en la documentaciòn: https://contactform7.com/recaptcha/

Comment: El problema aqui es que lo configure con las llaves pero no se muestra en la parte inferior derecha